# Precedência nas declarações de atributos/evento em TAGs fazem diferença? Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularjs-directives, atributos

Trabalho com AngularJs e Angular2+ a quase dois anos e recentemente, no Angular2+, me deparei com uma situação diferente que me fez pensar se foi mera coincidência ou por razão da versão do Angular que estou utilizando. Mas alguém sabe o motivo ou já passou por isto que informo abaixo?

**Exemplo:**

*ps: Atentar para o evento ngModelChange e ngModel*

**Declarar uma tag de INPUT com a seguinte ordem:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="valor.numero" (ngModelChange)="validarValor()"/>
```

**É diferente de inverter a ordem dos atributos:**

```
<input (ngModelChange)="validarValor()" [(ngModel)]="valor.numero"/>
```

Na primeira situação, consigo utilizar o valor.numero no método validarValor normalmente, coisa que não consigo fazer utilizando a segunda situação pois o valor encontra-se ainda não setado.

Realmente a precedência dos atributos/eventos/parâmetros de TAG importam?

Fica ai tbm a dica, caso alguém esteja passando pelo problema que passei, pois a princípio eu n estava conseguindo manipular o valor, pois ainda não tinha sido setado.

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0):

A ordem dos atributos não importam, fazem parte do mesmo `array` de atributos. O que pode estar acontecendo é que como as diretivas estão com bind, faz com que um atributo dependa do outro. No seu exemplo execute o método `validarValor()` depois de atribuir o `ngModel` ao `valor.numero`.